# Манипуляции с изображением в PictureBox

Tags: c#

Как изменить размер картинки загруженной в pictureBox

Comment: ну наверно так... [тынц](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982033/resizing-picturebox-proportionally-to-form-resizing?answertab=votes#tab-top)
или [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646287/image-scaling-of-picture-box?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @ЛазизЭргашев спасибо